# How to print an element of a string vector which was inserted using a variable of type "std::any"

Tags: c++, c++17, stdany

Here is my c++ Code's main function.

```
int main() {
vector<string> a;
any x;
x="Hello";
a.insert(a.begin(),any_cast<string>(x));
cout<<a[0]<<endl;
}
```

and this is giving me an error like this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_any_cast'
  what():  bad any_cast
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, `"Hello"` is of type `const char[6]` and would decay to `const char*`, it's not `std::string`. That's why you got `std::bad_any_cast` when trying to get `std::string` from the `std::any`.

You can change to get `const char*` like

```
a.insert(a.begin(),any_cast<const char*>(x));
```

Or assign `std::string` to the `std::any` from the beginning.

```
x=std::string("Hello");
```

Or use [literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) (since C++14)

```
x="Hello"s;
```

Comment: Then what about if the vector was of type int and I stored an int value in X.

Comment: @AviH Do you have any trouble with that? It should work fine. [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jzlCFQ6bbuE278OT)

Comment: thanks a lot . The string thingie that you said worked. Thanks soooo much..

Comment: Hey sorry but it's showing the same error with a double value. . The string worked but now double is showing a problem.

Comment: @AviH Please create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or show your code.

Comment: Hey it's fixed sorry was busy these few days.i just had to use double()